# GraphQL [graphql js] circular dependencies: The type of * must be Output Type but got: [object Object]

Tags: graphql-js, circular-reference, express-graphql

**EDIT**

added my solution as an answer

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

i believe this issue has to do with circular dependencies. i spent the better half of last night and today trying everything i could find online but nothing seems to work.

what i have tried:

- convert the `fields` prop to a function that returns a field object
- convert the relating fields (within the fields prop) into functions that return the type
- combining the two approaches above
- finally ending with require statements in place of the fields that use the reference type (does not seem correct and the linter had a stroke over this one)

**here is the file structure:**

[image: File Structure]

here is the code:

**`userType.js`**

```
const graphql = require('graphql');
const Connection = require('../../db/connection');
const ConnectionType = require('../connection/connectionType');

const { GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLList, GraphQLString, GraphQLID } = graphql;

const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    username: { type: GraphQLString },
    email: { type: GraphQLString },
    created: {
      type: GraphQLList(ConnectionType),
      resolve: ({ id }) => Connection.find({ owner: id }),
    },
    joined: {
      type: GraphQLList(ConnectionType),
      resolve: ({ id }) => Connection.find({ partner: id }),
    },
  }),
});

module.exports = UserType;
```

**`connectionType.js`**

```
const graphql = require('graphql');
const User = require('../../db/user');
const UserType = require('../user/userType');

const { GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLString, GraphQLID, GraphQLInt } = graphql;

const ConnectionType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Connection',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    owner: {
      type: UserType,
      resolve: ({ owner }) => User.findById(owner),
    },
    partner: {
      type: UserType,
      resolve: ({ partner }) => User.findById(partner),
    },
    title: { type: GraphQLString },
    description: { type: GraphQLString },
    timestamp: { type: GraphQLString },
    lifespan: { type: GraphQLInt },
  }),
});

module.exports = ConnectionType;
```

Comment: Your types look fine, except that `GraphQLList(ConnectionType)` should be `new GraphQLList(ConnectionType)` since that is a class

Comment: thanks i tried that a little after i posted this. none of it works but it looks correct to me. i dont get it

Comment: Where exactly do you get that error from the question title?

Comment: the graphiql client on load

Comment: Honestly can't tell what the problem might be. Can you reproduce this on a smaller standalone example?

Comment: i cant do it in a standalone (if you mean a single script). the problem has to do with circular dependencies with several scripts

Comment: Do you mean to say that this only happens if not all types are in the same file?

Comment: hey man just wanted to let you know i went into a hole for several hours nd figured it out myself. updated the question with my solution if you want to look @zoran404

Answer (score 2):

i couldnt get any help on this anywhere. in case anyone runs into this error message here are the steps i took to fix it:

1. switched from `graphql-express` to `apollo-server-express` (this was not necessary but i found apollo to be a more robust library)
2. used the following packages: `graphql graphql-import graphql-tools`
3. switched from javascript based Type defs to using the GraphQL SDL (`.graphql`) file type
4. step 3 is what corrected the circular import issue associated with one-to-many (and m2m) relationships

i committed every step of the refactor from dumping the old code to creating the new. i added plenty of notes and explicit naming so that it should be usable as a guide.

you can see the commit history diffs through the links below. all of the work until the last few commits was done within the `graphql/` directory. if you click the title of the commit it will show you the diff so you can follow the refactor

- [Last refactor with one-to-many relationship using apollo and GraphQL SDL Type defs](https://github.com/chingu-x/chingu-connect/tree/refactor/%2320_apollo)
- [commit history, start at `Scrapped old GraphQL setup`](https://github.com/chingu-x/chingu-connect/commits/refactor/%2320_apollo)

after the refactor i now have cleaner resolvers, a better directory pattern, and, most importantly, fully functioning one-to-many relationships between User and Connection! ...only took my entire goddamn day.

the relationship in this case is:
Connection belongs to an owner (User through owner_id) and partner (User through partner_id).

we will be moving forward from here with the codebase but i locked the branch and its commits for anyone who needs a guide.

Comment: Yeah, switching to sdl type defs was probably the easiest solution. I really like your app structure now.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue using Typescript, and I kinda like the javascript based Type definition better so didn't change to GraphQL SDL.

I got it to work just by specifying the type of const to GraphQLObjectType.

Something like:

```
export const UserType: GraphQLObjectType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'UserType',
  fields: () => ({
    .....
  })
}
```

Now it works without a problem.

Comment: Is that valid syntax? Looks like a typescript export.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention it’s in TypeScript.

Comment: you should update your answer with that information. the question i asked did not specify a language so its a valid answer. but its worth clarifying for anyone who comes across this post.