# resource and references for one/many to many relationship in graphql?

Tags: many-to-many, graphql, one-to-many, relationships, graphql-js

i feel like im going crazy here. spent the last couple hours searching and there is not one single official or complete source of information on this topic. all that i have found are vague 10 line of code representations of how relationships would look in the typedefs but no implementation details **anywhere**!

i thought this would be a **very** common use case in graphql. why is nobody talking about it?

are there any resources you can recommend on implementing o2m and m2m relationships? am i thinking of this wrong and this isnt something graphql supports?

[here is the implementation i am stuck on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50161256/graphql-graphql-js-circular-dependencies-the-type-of-must-be-output-type-bu) (i believe caused by circular references).

Comment: If you give examples of o2m and m2m queries I can give you examples of how to implement graphql schema for handling them.

Comment: do you want me to write them here or would you mind joining me on discord / hangouts? i have a simple (2 types) application that i am trying to relate. everything works until i implement the relationship

Comment: You can post it in your question, so others can see what I'm referencing

Comment: check out zero-to-graphql. Quite a minimal example in different languages, but includes DB, schema and everything. Also demonstrates many-to-many relations  https://github.com/steveluscher/zero-to-graphql

Comment: keep running into what i believe to be a circular reference issue. have been at it for about 10 hours total now. tried everything i could find online. eventually backed up to start searching "relationship modeling in graphql" for a couple hours. and here i am

Comment: sure. i actually posted it earlier and didnt get any votes. i will add the link now

Comment: zero-to-graphql (referenced above) has a pretty nice example, probably should check it out

Comment: yep got it open already. taking a look. do you feel that conversation about modeling relationships in graphql is a little sparse? am i thinking about this the right way?

Comment: that github is for a single Person Type. there are no relationships in it (at least the node dir)

Comment: I would agree, the material on this subject is quite sparse at the moment. I get a lot of questions about it. zero-to-graphql helps a lot in this respect. Also "How to GraphQL" has info on this as well (here is a scala-based example): https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-scala/7-relations/

Comment: That's true, there is only a single person type, but it is a recursive type. so there is a relation between person and it's friends (which are of the same type): https://github.com/steveluscher/zero-to-graphql/blob/master/zero-node/schema.js#L63-L68

Comment: right. but the issue im having is caused by circular references / dependencies. modular type defs for organization. while the Person example covers an aspect of relationships it doesnt help with the circular issue because its all internal to the type.

Comment: Also, if scala is your thing, I there is another example with 2 different types: categories and products and different relation types between these https://sangria-graphql.org/learn/#high-level-fetch-api

Comment: thanks but i havent worked with scala. the logic makes sense in any language the syntax (graphql js in this case) im missing.

Answer (score 0):

i couldnt get an answer to either of my questions. so i figured it out myself and documented the solution through about 20 commits of refactoring. you [can see my original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50161256/graphql-graphql-js-circular-dependencies-the-type-of-must-be-output-type-bu/50166929#50166929) that led me to seeking relationship modeling resources. i answered the question and gave details and links to the refactor.

before someone edits this answer out i believe it does count as an answer. i provided a resource for someone seeking to model relationships in graphql.